# How to enable taking of a photo directly in a HTML page (and not opening the camera app)?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, camera

I know the

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

method to allow the user to take a picture (and similar other examples [here](http://anssiko.github.io/html-media-capture/) with `accept="video/*"`, etc.), and when using this, **clicking on the `<input>` usually opens the phone's camera app**, allows the user to take a photo, and then goes back to the original page.

But how, with Javascript, to have a preview of the camera **directly in a HTML page, in a `<div>`** and a "Take photo" button, i.e. not have to open the phone's camera app?

(Of course the user would have to grant access to the phone camera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this tutorial](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/), I finally found the solution using [`getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

NB: since recent versions of Chrome, for security reasons, it only works if the site is HTTPS. You can start Chrome with `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://123.123.123.123"` if you want to test it on a non-HTTPS website.

```js
var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
var audioSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

getStream().then(getDevices).then(gotDevices);

function getDevices() { return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(); }

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  window.deviceInfos = deviceInfos; 
  for (const deviceInfo of deviceInfos) {
const option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') { option.text = deviceInfo.label || `Microphone ${audioSelect.length + 1}`; audioSelect.appendChild(option); } 
if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') { option.text = deviceInfo.label || `Camera ${videoSelect.length + 1}`; videoSelect.appendChild(option); }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (window.stream) { window.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => { track.stop(); }); }
  const audioSource = audioSelect.value;
  const videoSource = videoSelect.value;
  const constraints = { audio: {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined}, video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined} };
  return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream;
  audioSelect.selectedIndex = [...audioSelect.options].findIndex(option => option.text === stream.getAudioTracks()[0].label);
  videoSelect.selectedIndex = [...videoSelect.options].findIndex(option => option.text === stream.getVideoTracks()[0].label);
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) { console.error('Error: ', error); }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="select"><label for="audioSource">Audio source: </label><select id="audioSource"></select></div>
<div class="select"><label for="videoSource">Video source: </label><select id="videoSource"></select></div>
<video autoplay muted playsinline></video>
</div>
```